# How to use/show different path alias of same URL according to user roles?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

Hi I have set URL alias of for node add from path like below :

> 1. node/add/my_content_type =  addlink
> 2. node/add/my_content_type  = suggestion

When user is logged-in we make access of node add form via this URL:

> www.example.com/addlink

Now for not logged-in user we want users to use node add from via below URL:

> www.example.com/suggestion

I am trying with rules on event "Initialize drupal" then checking path and roles and trying to redirect but not able to achieve that.

Please suggest is that possible to make it happen in some way!

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why it matters to have two URLs that go to the same thing? Is it the same content type?

Comment: Yes it is same content type "node/add/link" but for logged in users /link and for not logged in it should be /suggestions as this is requirement because not logged in users can submit only unpublished nodes so those are suggestions and logged in users can add nodes and publish them!

Comment: Why not create two menu items with hook_menu and simply set the user access permission? Then you can add that link to any menu, and users will either see it not based on their access permissions (similar to Login/Logout/My Account). Would be easier to me than rewriting and aliasing URLs.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for suggestion, I am going to try that !!

Comment: By default any menu link or link created with the l() function will check access. So while you will have two separate items, users would never know it.

Answer (score 3):

The ensure the right path is used when displaying links, you need to implement [`hook_url_outbound_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7.x) in a custom module.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_url_outbound_alter().
 */
function MODULE_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  if ($path == 'node/add/my_content_type') {
    $path = user_is_logged_in() ? 'addlink' : 'suggestion';
  }
}
```

Ensuring the right path is always used can be achieved with a [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x). There, you can alter the page callback for `node/add/my_content_type`. And in your callback, check whether the user is accessing the page using the expected path.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MODULE_hook_menu_alter(&$items) {
   $type_url_str = str_replace('_', '-', 'my_content_type');
   $items[['node/add/' . $type_url_str]['page callback'] = 'MODULE_my_content_type_add';
}

/**
 * Page callback for the add new My Content node page.
 *
 * @see MODULE_hook_menu_alter
 */
function MODULE_my_content_type_add($type) {
  $expected_path = user_is_logged_in() ? 'addlink' : 'suggestion';
  if (current_path() != $expected_path) {
    drupal_goto($expected_path);
  }
  else {
    return node_add($type);
  }
}
```

If you site use multiple language with prefix language selector, then `current_path()` will also contains the language prefix whch need to be accounted for in your code.

Comment: Thank you for answer as I can see it start changing path according to user is logged in or not. Thanks for explanations and code. But It created problem ie: node/add/ from page is not loading it says "redirected you too many times." please sugggest !

Comment: Check the value of `current_path()`, after redirection it should match the `$expected_path`. Otherwise you end up with a infinite redirection loop.

Comment: current path is "node/add/link" but expected path says "addlink" or "suggestion" as we set Path alias for them.

Comment: Please suggest as per our paths current_path and expected path are not equal due to which it should enter in loop but drupal_goto($expected_path) is not working but its entering infinite loop instead. sorry to bother you for asking more details.

Comment: we are using 2 languages but those are based on domain so no language prefix is used! but we are using entity translation.

Comment: `current_path()` should return the alias used to access the page (either `addlink` or `suggestion`), not the unaliased path (ie. `node/add/link`).

Comment: In menu in have added alias but it changes back to original node/add/link path after saving menu item. But while accessing  menu item it gives path alias but not original path , seems something wrong with my menu items

Comment: I have accepted yesterday late night but it still enters in infinite loop, Now my current_path() returns  (either addlink or suggestion), not the unaliased path (ie. node/add/link). I think some other issue is there, please suggest if anything I am doing wrong !

Comment: You want current_path() to return the aliased path since you want to ensure the user is using the expected alias, and redirect otherwise. If you have a redirect loop, then something is wrong with that comparison. Do you have any other code or module causing a redirection? Do the redirection loop happen for anonymous and authenticated users?

Comment: I do not have any redirection due to other module but to verify that I have tried on complete fresh install of Drupal with creating content type and alias as required but problem remained same.Redirection loop happen for both anonymous and authenticated users.

Another thing I tried instead of using current_path() I tried to use variable $currentpath and value of variable is set equal to alias such as "addnode" or "suggestion" depending on user is logged-in or not. But it still enters into loop for both users. Not able to understand why this is happening. Further guidance much appreciated!

Comment: when using $currentpath as variable as mentioned in previous comment, redirect loop stops but only one alias works for both cases ie: suggestion

Comment: Thank you! for all help but my purpose got solved by answer I have posted now.  Sorry for removing accept as it was not working for me. But really very thankful that you spent such time for  helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to solve this by using [theme_menu_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7.x):

```
function theme_menu_link__main_menu(array $variables) {



  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#original_link']['mlid'] == "610") {

       if ($element['#original_link']['mlid'] == "610") {

          $path = user_is_anonymous() ? 'suggestion' : 'addlink';
          $element['#original_link']['link_path'] = $path;
          $element['#href'] = $path;
     }
  }

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '' . $output . $sub_menu . "\n";

}
```

Comment: Just note that this only works when the link is in the main menu. If you use the link in other menus, or in content (like body text) it won't do what you want. Hence the hook_menu suggestion. You can also remove global $user here and just use user_is_anonymous() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_anonymous/7.x

Comment: Also, if someone ever mistakenly deletes the menu link and re-adds it, this code will no longer work.

Comment: Thanks those are valid points and I have removed global user and will try with suggestion!!